# Laravel. Model Factory. Many-To-Many relation

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, model, factory

I have problem with many-to-many relation on model factory.

For example:
There are `users`, `roles` and `user_role` tables. 
I have defined model factories for `user` and `roles`. Next I try to add role to user:

```
$role = factory(Role::class)->create();
config(['admin_group_id' => $role->id]);
$admin = factory(User::class)->create();
$admin->roles()->save($role);
```

It's work, but when I get `$admin->roles()->first()->id` it not equal `$role->id`

Comment: are you sure config(['admin_group_id' => $role->id]); is correct? what file are you storing this admin_group_id in? its usually something like config('myfile.myfield', $value) isnt it?

Comment: it's just example. I don't understand why `$admin->roles()->first()->id` it not equal `$role->id` after saving role to user

Comment: what is the relationship? a belongsToMany?

Comment: Yes, belongsToMany

Comment: see my answer - should get you fixed up

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `save()` you should be using `attach()` and pass in the id of the role